# Authlogic - how to redirect after login on a different page, when is that the first time?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, redirect, authentication, authlogic

I use **Authlogic** gem for authentication in my app and I try to add a feature, that when is the user logged-in first time, so I want to redirect him on the welcome "page". In the DB table is the column `login_count`.

In the **UserSessionsController** I try to use this code:

```
  def create
    @user_session = UserSession.new(params[:user_session])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @user_session.save
        if current_user.login_count == 1
          format.html { redirect_to(root_url+'welcome') }
        else
          format.html { redirect_to(root_url+'profile_page') }
        end
        format.xml  { render :xml => @user_session, :status => :created, :location => @user_session }
      else
        format.html { redirect_to :signin_user_sessions
                      flash[:warning] = 'Bad log-in credentials.' 
                    }
        format.xml  { render :xml => @user_session.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }         
      end
    end
  end
```

But I am getting in this case the error message

> undefined method `login_count' for nil:NilClass

I use **Authlogic** with the usual setup.

Where I should place the redirect logic with the testing of how many times was this user already logged in?

Comment: Paste the code for `login_count` which I assume is defined on the User model, right? Btw, you would want to be placing redirect logic on login, in your ApplicationController.